# HD 3450 Radeon Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I've looked everywhere for something helpful getting this driver installed. I have this computer hooked up to a TV and the Tv itself does not have a Monitor feature (Panasonic TCP50X1) and I want to adjust the overscan so I can see the full screen. Also, this rig is set up for emulation I really need that extra power to balance the load on this old PC.

This link says it's compatible but says nothing about how to install or at least not where I can see. I've been battling for nearly a week now and I'm out of ideas. I'd also take a way to set the underscan just so it will display properly and I could put the graphics card on the back burner for a moment... Currently Running Ubuntu 17.10

Sorry if it says how to install but I cannot find it there. I installed the .run driver from AMD but it ended up crashing my PC and I had to reinstall because I couldn't undo whatever it did. Tried twice but it was a fresh install so not much lost.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: The wiki didn't mention 17.10, but implied to me it was installed by default (if recognized in your hardware & you ran the correct kernel) for 14.04LTS & 16.04LTS. It gave tons of information about recognizing your card; information used by the installer/kernel in recognizing cards.  If you followed what was there, and it responded just as per the wiki, I'd assume you have that driver (can you see it with `lsmod`?)    note: I'm no expert in video modules.

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-to-turn-off-overscan-on-panasonic-plasma-626504/

Comment: Sorry, I'm still super new to Linux. I didn't realize this existed, I kept seeing intel on other commands I would run but this showed I do have radeon installed... Question is, how do I change my overscan?

Comment: Actually, I found out that the driver in use is snd_hda_intel if that helps.